# Training adjustments of synaptic Weights

Tags: neural-network

I'm a graduate student in the Electrical Engineering Program currently working on my thesis and I have to figure out how to train synaptic weights in an Artificial Neural Network either analogously or digitally.

Can anyone suggest some base papers that I can read to get started on this and how I can proceed. Would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this question is really on-topic for psych & neuroscience (but others may disagree with me) - Cross Validated might be better but they will probably prefer a more specific question rather than a broad reference request. I'd start by reading papers in your field that use ANNs and read the papers they cite for their methods.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but it is where I've started in the past: See Andrew Ng's *Machine Learning* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeHZOdmJvFU&list=PLZ9qNFMHZ-A4rycgrgOYma6zxF4BZGGPW To get familiar with the algorithms for training machine learning see the Python package Scikit-Learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html These are general resources and you may be well beyond this already.

Comment: @BryanKrause would Bioinformatics be an alternative?

Comment: No bioinformatics would not.

Comment: What do you mean by "analogously or digitally"? Like, analogue neuromorphic hardware?